# High memory consumption in generating a graph in python

Tags: python, graph

I'm using python to generate a graph from a file. 
When I run my code it uses around 7 GB of my RAM!! (the graph has 1,600,00 nodes)

The input file is something like this:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 4
```

each row represents an edge. in this example we have 4 nodes and 4 edges.

Here is my code:

```
class Graph(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.node_list = []
        self.edge = []
        self.neighbors = {}
        with open(infile, "r") as source_file:
            for row in csv.reader(source_file, delimiter='\t'):
                self.node_list.append(int(row[0]))
                self.node_list.append(int(row[1]))
                self.edge.append(row)
        for node in self.edge:
            if node[0] in self.neighbors:
                self.neighbors[node[0]].append(node[1])
            else:
                self.neighbors[node[0]] = [node[1]]
            if node[1] in self.neighbors:
                self.neighbors[node[1]].append(node[0])
            else:
               self.neighbors[node[1]] = [node[0]]
        self.node_list = list(set(self.node_list))

g = Graph()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How *precisely* did you measure how much RAM it used? What tool did you use, and what *precisely* did it report?

Comment: I used top command in Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, so what *precisely* did it report? Are you reporting the VIRT field? The RES field? Or what?

Comment: I ran my program one more time and I measured the RAM usage using htop tool and now I'm reporting the Mem field: 7100 - 7800 out of 11952 MB RAM

Comment: There is no mem field. There's VIRT, RES, SHR. Do you mean MEM%?

Comment: @Pymal how many edges does the graph has? (i.e. how many lines your csv file has?) Could you please edit the number of nodes (1.6M or 160k)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for you comments. I'm using htop, it does have a field called Mem. Which field are you looking for? I can report that to you.

Comment: @jimifiki My graph has 1.6M nodes and 15M edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong data structures in the wrong way.

Your code creates a huge number of redundant entries in the node list. Using your example, the node list will be:

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4]
```

which when handling 1'600'000 nodes is going to add considerably to your data requirements. Then you store a complete copy of the input file in `self.edge` which is never released.

You don't even need a class for what you are doing:

```
import collections

graph = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open(infile) as inf:
    for line in inf.read():
        p, q = line.split()
        if p not in graph[q]:
            graph[q].append(p)
        if q not in graph[p]:
            graph[p].append(q)
```

`graph` now contains a minimal representation of your input file. This is a [rather old pattern](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) which has worked well. You may find a package like [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) to be useful if you want to do anything with the graph once created.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, I used class because I need to have access to a list of node's neighbors as well. But as you and @jimifiki mentioned, there is no need to generate self.edge

Comment: A graph has a list of each nodes neighbors, that's the point of a graph. If I need the list of the neighbors of `1`, then `graph[1]` contains `[2, 3, 4]`. Similarly, `graph[2]` contains `[1, 4]`. The contents of `graph[3]` and `graph[4]` are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: "if x not in graph[x]" may be problematic given that graph[x] is a list. Probably better to use "graph = collections.defaultdict(set)". Although, given that the average degree is only about 15 (15 million edges / 1 million vertices), it probably won't be too inefficient.

Comment: @msw your code doesn't seem efficient!  when I run it my RAM usage goes to 8GB! because the idea is the same! I need a better solution, Or might be I have to switch to C++

Comment: @Pymal a) I gave you an alternative, but mostly b) what do you expect trying to put 1.6 million nodes with 15 million edges in memory? Hint: how much memory would 16.6 million integers with no graph properties at all take in memory?

Comment: @msw I really appreciate your help. The integer size in python is 24 Bytes: 24 * 16,000,000 = 384,000,000. to convert it to MB: 384,000,000 / (2^20) = 366.2 MBytes

Answer (score 2):

IMHO self.node_list is useless once __init__ has run. You shouldn't bind it to self. 
Moreover I cannot understand why you need self.edge in such a format. You probably don't need it at all.

self.neighbors probably provides a good enough descritpion of your graph.

Comment: as I figured out, the main problem is creating a huge dictionary in python which is Memory consuming! Now I'm trying to use list instead of dictionary but I haven't been successful so far as I'm not professional in Python.

Comment: If you need to retrieve elements (the list of neighbouring) by key (the node) you can associate an integer ordinal tag to each node and use it as if it was a key. Is it what you are trying to do right now?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution or its variations to improve memory usage. 
Give a try.

The idea is that you associate to each node an integer ordinal tag 
and you use that tag to access to the list containing the neighors lists.

```
import csv 
class Graph(object):
        def __init__(self,infile):
        tags = {} 
        self.neighbors = []
        with open(infile, "r") as source_file:
            for row in csv.reader(source_file, delimiter=' '):
            node1 = int(row[0]) 
            node2 = int(row[1]) 
            if node1 not in tags:
                tags[node1] = len(tags) 
                self.neighbors.append([])
            if node2 not in tags:
                tags[node2] = len(tags) 
                self.neighbors.append([])
            self.neighbors[tags[node1]].append(tags[node2])  
            self.neighbors[tags[node2]].append(tags[node1])  
    def getNodes(self):
        return xrange(len(self.neighbors))
    def getNeighs(self,i):
        return self.neighbors[i]
g = Graph('infile.txt')

print "MyNodes:\n ",
print [i for i in g.getNodes()] 
print 'myNeighs\n ', 
for i in g.getNodes(): 
    print g.getNeighs(i),
```

let me show a possible variant. Notice that in both cases the 
dictionary 'tags' can be garbage collected (i.e. deleted) after 
__init__ has run because nothing refers to it. You are left 
with lists only.

```
import csv 
class Graph2(object):
        def __init__(self,infile):
        tags = {} 
        self.inverseTags = [] 
        self.neighbors = []
        with open(infile, "r") as source_file:
            for row in csv.reader(source_file, delimiter=' '):
            node1 = int(row[0]) 
            node2 = int(row[1]) 
            if node1 not in tags:
                tags[node1] = len(tags) 
                self.neighbors.append([])
                self.inverseTags.append(node1)
            if node2 not in tags:
                tags[node2] = len(tags) 
                self.neighbors.append([])
                self.inverseTags.append(node2)
            self.neighbors[tags[node1]].append(tags[node2])  
            self.neighbors[tags[node2]].append(tags[node1])  
    def getNodes(self):
        return xrange(len(self.neighbors))
    def getNodesOriginalNames(self):
        return (self.inverseTags[i] for i in xrange(len(self.neighbors)))
    def getNeighs(self,i):
        return self.neighbors[i]
    def getNeighsOriginalName(self,i):
        return [self.inverseTags[j] for j in self.neighbors[i]]
g = Graph2('infile.txt')

print "MyNodes:\n ",
print [i for i in g.getNodesOriginalNames()] 
print 'myNeighs\n ', 
for i in g.getNodes(): 
    print g.getNeighsOriginalName(i),
```

Of course if in your csv file the node's names are already zero-based 
ordinals you can save all the translation work that __init__ is doing.